# JAX-WS changing namespace for WebParam

Tags: web-services, namespaces, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

We're working with JAX-WS in conjuntion with JAXB (2.1).

First, we've created the Java classes linked to the XSDs types.

Then, using CXF (2.1.3), Spring (2.0.8) and JAX-WS we've published a Webservice from a JAXB type (in fact a @XmlType), like this:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "addExample")
public @WebResult void addExample(
        @WebParam(name = "EXAMPLE") EXAMPLETYPE exemple);
```

We know that the webservice is published using the package name of the interface (inverse) or using the @WebService annotation the "targetNamespace" we could define. In fact, we did it with something like:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://blablabla")
```

At this time, we need to maintain the whole targetNameSpace of the WebService but we need to change the namespace of the @java.jws.WebParam (i.e EXAMPLE param in our case).

It is possible? The annotation never works for us, doing things like that:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "addExample")
public @WebResult void addExample(
        @WebParam(name = "EXAMPLE", targetNamespace = "http://thats.all.folks") EXAMPLETYPE exemple);
```

We are really lost...

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to upgrade to a newer (and supported) version of CXF.   I believe this was a bug that was fixed a very long time ago.

Comment: Yees??? Omg!!! You don't know how much time I've spent on this! I'll try it to update it to the latest (2.4.0) next days!

Thank you very much Daniel!!

Comment: Daniel it works! We upgrade CXF to the latest 2.2.12 (we can't go up because the use of Spring 3 :-() and everything works like a charm!
Thank you!